# Infinite Looping Caused by Exception Handling

Tags: java, input, exception, while-loop, infinite-loop

What I want this code to do is handle the exception, and then simply repeat. What it does instead, unfortunately, is loop infinitely... I can't figure out why.

It never asks for the input to be re-entered, seemingly setting it for good the first time. However, this ONLY happens when an exception is thrown; if the user enters an invalid integer, there is no problem at all with the looping process.

I'm relatively new to all this, so I was hoping to get a second opinion before just forcing the loop to exit when an exception is caught.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

// Variables associated with the clock:
private int h; // h = Hours
private int m; // m = Minutes
private int s; // s = Seconds

public boolean userPrompt() {

    String answer = "";

    // Loops while until a clock is generated and selected
    while (! answer.equals("y")) {

        System.out.println("What time is it?");

        try {

            // Asking for the time, one variable at a time.
            System.out.print("H >> ");
            h = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("M >> ");
            m = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.print("S >> ");
            s = scan.nextInt();

            // Testing for the validity of the clock's time:
            if ((h < 24 && h >= 0) && (m < 60 && m >= 0) && (s < 60 && s >= 0)) {

                // Displaying the formatted clock's time:
                System.out.printf("Clock { %02d:%02d:%02d }\n", h, m, s);

                System.out.println("Save clock generated?");

                System.out.print("Answer (y/n): ");
                answer = scan.next();
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException iox) {

            // Here lies the issue, I think...
            System.out.println("ERROR: " +iox);
        }
    }

    // A safeguard for the next method in the program
    return answer.equals("y");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `finally` after `catch` block and put the following two statements in it like this :

```
  try {


  } catch(InputMismatchException iox) {


  } finally {

   System.out.print("Answer (y/n): ");
            answer = scan.next();

 }
```

Note : When exception occurs before  `System.out.print("Answer (y/n): ");` and
                `answer = scan.next();` statements,these two statements are not executed.But the statements within the `finally` block executes regardless of what happens within the `try` block.So,if you use the two statements in `finally` block these will always be executed infinite looping won't happen.

Comment: +1 You could always put the `answer = scan.next()` on the outside of the try/catch block too. Depends on how the OP is trying to solve the problem.